# How to implement for cycle in jmeter

Tags: loops, for-loop, jmeter, counter

I'm new in jmeter and would like to implement a for cycle as this:

```
for(int i=0; i < max; i+ = sample)
```

I have tried with loop controller and Counter but i can not to increment i variable with sample but only with unitary value.

I didn't found the for structure in jmeter.

I have already tried writing this code to try:

[image: jmeter code]

Someone has an idea about how do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are close how it is right now.  Your counter should start at 0, and increment by the value of the variable ${sample}.  However, the syntax for reference name looks invalid.

Also, no matter what your counter is your loop is going to iterate 5 times, because ${max} is 5.

In the counter, replace:

```
Reference Name = ${i}
```

with:

```
Reference Name = i
```

This should make five iterations, with i going from 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.

Also, you may want to leave the "number format" section blank.

Edit: Removed JMX XML as it did not quite answer the question (and was quite messy).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried with this but with increment of 1, sample=1 and max = 5 I obtained : 0-1-2-3-4
Else with sample=2 : 0-2-4-0-2 because the counter restart

Comment: The reason the counter is "restarting" is because of your Number Format = 0.  This is forcing it to always only have one digit.  It doesn't explain why there is no 8, but that is my best guess.  Also, just to be safe, you could set the max to very high on the counter.

Comment: i think that the reason of "restarting" is the parameter loop count = ${max} so the counter restart itself to do max times the cycle

Comment: Loop count = ${max} is why your loop goes 5 times no matter what.
Inside of your counter, is max set to ${max}?
I'm going to attach a JMX that is working fine.

Comment: yes, maximum=${max} so it restarts. But i want to iterate max/sample time

Comment: In that case, why not make a separate "loop_iterations" variable and set it to be equal to ${max}/${sample}?  That way the variable tracking the number of loop iterations is separate from the logic of incrementing your counter.

Comment: maybe i have fixed with this command :
${__javaScript(${max} / ${sample})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75510/discussion-between-luca-and-aa-ron).